# Setting iframes on pages

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a basic website that I'm working on and I would like to add an iframe to one of the pages. So what I want to do is have several links from the index page to another page. But depending on what link is chosen on the index page, the new page should open with that iframe being displayed.

You can view a rough draught of the site here: [www.hansmoolman.com](http://hansmoolman.com/)

If the user clicks on one of section in the middle that says "soups salads sandwiches....", they will be taken to the MENU page, but the menu page should reflect the choice they have made on the index page. Currently I have the iframe set up and the link to the menu page working, but it defaults to the "vegetarian" because it is hard-coded that way as you can see in the following line of code which links from the index page:

`<li><a href="vegetarian.html" target="inlineFrame">Vegetarians</a></li>`

to the menu page which displays the iframe as follows:

`<div class="inlineStyle">
                <iframe name="inlineFrame" src="vegetarian.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="108%" height="auto" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" ></iframe>
            </div>`

How can I make it so that my iframe automatically displays the choice that the user has selected on the index page? Would some sort of JavaScript (if else statement?) be the best solution her, or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Don't beg SO for answers.  Just ask the question as simply and clearly as possible.  Also read over your question at least once looking for spelling/grammatical errors.

Comment: I wasn't begging for an answer, I was simply asking for help. I thought that's what this site was for...?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an iframe snap to any `id` within an iframe using a fragment part of the url:

`<iframe src="vegetarian.html#choice"/>`

Now within vegetarian.html you can could have:

`<input id='choice' />`

Ant this input filed will be at the upper left corner of your iframe.